# Improvements to the "go to" line

Tags: feature-request

[image: list icons]

### **Please, can you ...**

**a)** ... put this line not only on bottom, but also on top of the list ?

**b)** ... add more than just 7 icons, and/or make other intervals? If you want to go to page 32, you need a while ... How about intervals in steps of 2^n ... 2, 4, 8, 16, ...

Comment: you can just edit the URL if you want to go to 32

Comment: ... we are programmers, we can do that.

Comment: Also, why would you want to go to page 32?  [Searching](http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) and google are a thing.

Comment: @Deduplicator Right, but then please remove the list at all. Actually, please add a big bash console window to stackexchange and make it a pretty command-line-oriented system.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I love questions beginning with "Also, why would you want ... "

Comment: @Giosco well you're asking for time spent from the dev team. People are trying to understand your need. Checking for page 32 seems.... not very useful

Comment: @Deduplicator Also, for programmers, a list with intervals of 1 is really pretty boring. If you want to add some spice, then make **binary intervals**, as suggested.

Comment: @Giosco why stop there?  Display every number in a hexadecimal format.  That would be not boring.  Very annoying but not boring.

Comment: @Ryanyuyu I'd prefer if usernames were in binary that I'd need to manually translate to ASCII actually

Comment: @ryanyuyu You are very right, I actually really hate decimals. I only celebrate birthdays at primes and powers of 2. So yes, **Hex** would be good !

Answer (score 8):

I don't think this would be very useful. Under what circumstances do you need to navigate to any page other than Previous, Next, Last, or just a few pages away from where you currently are? If you know *exactly* what page you want to go to, just edit that into the URL. I think the current design is flexible enough without being too busy.

Comment: Also, if you're dealing with that much data, it's probably time to use the search features and filter some out.  Or favorite tags.

Comment: I seriously disagree! I've been annoyed very often not having the _next page_ list at hand at the top, e.g. in the list of my favorite questions (where I'm actually keeping my _"dupe repostitory"_), and I'm sure finding the link I'm searching for will appear at the 2nd page. For people who know where they want to navigate, forcing them to scroll down 1st it would be a great improvement.

Comment: Made an answer from this comment.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Hit the Page Down button on your keyboard. The number of times that having the navigation at the top would be convenient is far outweighed by the number of times it would just be in the way.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Well, I have to admit I'm apparently not _using my keyboard efficiently_, as I said to slap s.o. else here recently. THX for letting me learn (triple face palm, I just didn't know that it's working out that simple way).